# How to check if an index exist in neo4j cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to find a way to check if a certain index exists in cypher schema indexes. I can find all the indexes by using `call db.indexes()` . but how can I check for a specific index?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the index to exist, I would recommend just running the Cypher to create the index. The result being that whether the index existed or not, after the call it is guaranteed to exist.

On the other hand, if you just want the information for display purposes or something, you can use [YIELD](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/call/#call-call-a-procedure-within-a-complex-query-using-call-yield) to continue a cypher from a [CALL](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/call/#call-call-a-procedure-using-call). For example...

```
CALL db.indexes() YIELD label, properties WHERE label="Person" RETURN *
```

For db.indexes, the variables you can yield are `description, label, properties, provider, state, type` (you have to yield them by name, `YIELD a,b,c,d,e,f` won't work)

Comment: even though I did it by parsing result this is pure gold .. thanks @Tezra

Comment: My problem is that neo4j throws an error if you try to create an index that already exists. Is there a way to create an index that won't throw an error if the index already exists?

Comment: @mcv Then either you need to put a lock on the caller so they know they already called create index, or use the APOC extention like cybersam suggests.

Comment: After neo4j 4.3 use the new Index creation syntax: [Neo4j: How to call "CREATE INDEX" only if not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65077125/262235)

Answer (score 4):

The APOC plugin has an [apoc.schema.node.indexExists](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/overview/apoc.schema/apoc.schema.node.indexExists) function for determining whether a specific index exists.

Comment: Yes, but how do you use it as a conditional? That will return `true` or `false`, but the value of that is meaningless in the real world unless you can make it part of another execution.

Comment: You can use the APOC procedures [apoc.when](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc/apoc.when/) or [apoc.do.when](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.do/apoc.do.when/) to perform if-then-else processing.