# Neo4j: How to call "CREATE INDEX" only if not exists

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The `CREATE INDEX <indexName>` command is not idempotent and will cause an error if the given index already exists. I'm new to neo4j, and can't find a predicate that avoids this error. I've tried various permutations of `ANY(...)`, and they all barf at "db.indexes()".

Since `CREATE INDEX ...` fails if the index exists and `DROP INDEX ...` fails if it doesn't, I don't know how to write a .cypher file that creates the index only if needed.

A short form might be something like `CREATE INDEX indexName FOR (c:SomeLabel) ON (c.someProperty) IF NOT EXISTS`, but of course that short form doesn't exist.

Is there some way to do this with a predicate, subquery or some such expression?

Comment: What's your version of Neo4j? Can you share the exact code you are executing?

Comment: Too bad I can't paste a screenshare. I'm running "Neo4j Server version: 4.0.0 (community). I pasted the code you posted into the input frame of the Neo Browser. I got the same results by running the following from a bash command line: 'cypher-shell -u neo4j -p neo4j "CREATE INDEX ON :Car (id)"'

Comment: Is there some chance that there's a config option someplace that causes Neo4j to silently ignore errors like this? I'm pretty sure that when I invoke these from the python driver, it raises an exception that I can then catch and handle. I see that cypher-shell does fail with a return code of -1, so maybe that's the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried both suggestions, and neither solves my issue. I don't have time to discover, through trial-and-error, how to install APOC in my environment.

The first line of mbh86's answer is inaccurate, at least in my system. The command is not ignored, it fails with an error. So if anything else is in the same cypher script, it will fail.

The best I can do is apparently to wrap the CREATE INDEX in a command-line string, run that string from either a bash or python script, run it, and check the return code from the calling program.

I appreciate the effort of both commentators, and I didn't want to leave either hanging.

Answer (score 12):

As of Neo4j 4.1.3, a new index creation syntax has been introduced to do just that

`CREATE INDEX myIndex IF NOT EXISTS FOR (t:Test) ON (t.id)`

[Indexes for search performance](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/indexes-for-search-performance/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [apoc.schema.node.indexExists](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.5/indexes/schema-index-operations/#_schema_information) function to check whether an index exists before creating it.

For example, this query will create the `:Foo(id)` index if it does not already exist:

```
WITH 1 AS ignored
WHERE NOT apoc.schema.node.indexExists('Foo', ['id'])
CALL db.createIndex('index_name', ['Foo'], ['id'], 'native-btree-1.0') YIELD name, labels, properties
RETURN name, labels, properties
```

For some reason, the Cypher planner currently is not able to parse the normal `CREATE INDEX index_name ...` syntax after the above `WHERE` clause, so this query uses the [db.createIndex](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/index-configuration/#index-configuration-btree-procedures) procedure instead.

There is also a much more powerful APOC procedure, [apoc.schema.assert](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/indexes/schema-index-operations/#_schema_information), but it may be overkill for your requirements.

Comment: My neo browser complains that "apoc.schema.node.indexExists" is an unknown function in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Is the APOC plugin [installed](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/introduction/#installation)?

Comment: Heh. Plugin? What plugin? I'll try that and see what happens. I'm already able to get the list of index names by doing "CALL db.indexes() YIELD name", but I don't know how to get the results in-scope in Cypher. I'm finding it hard to find specific information like this in the docs.

Comment: Sorry, not going to happen. I run neo4j in a headless guest VM running CentOS7, hosted on a Windows 10 pro system. I see no indication that the "Neo4j desktop", installed on Windows, will connect to the server running on the VM. The install script wants to put things inside the Windows file system, which has no neo4j installation at all. I see no way to install apoc from the command line and no ability to do the same from the Neo browser.

Comment: You don't need Neo4j Desktop to install APOC, you can download a release [from GH](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases) manually stick it in the `$NEO4J_HOME/plugins` folder. You need to also tell Neo4j you trust this plugin to operate outside of the procedure sandbox, something like adding `dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*` to your `neo4j.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the command is ignored if the index exists.
Can you test the following?

```
CREATE (n:Car {id: 1});
```

*Added 1 label, created 1 node, set 1 property, completed after 23 ms.*

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Car (id);
```

1st execution: *Added 1 index, completed after 6 ms.*

2nd execution : *(no changes, no records)*

Comment: The second and subsequent attempts fail with the same complaint I've been seeing:

cypher-shell -u neo4j -p neo4j "CREATE INDEX ON :Car (id)"
An equivalent index already exists, 'Index( 7, 'index_1b145ec8', GENERAL BTREE, :Car(id), native-btree-1.0 )'.

Comment: **Before version 4.0** of Neo4j, the create index command was actually ignored if the index already existed. This behavior has changed with the introduction of Neo4j 4.0.

Comment: In 3.5, the driver throws an error if you create an index that already exists. But the browser does not. Curious difference.